# How to let YouTube embed video container overflow page

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I have iframe with youtube embed video. It has some styles so it can be responsive to screen's width, you can see below.

HTML:

```
<main role="main" class="container">
<div class="main-video fixed-top justify-content-center">
    <iframe class="video" width="1920" height="1080"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T0-P3AS4U4U?modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&color=white">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-video {
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
}

.main-video > .video {
    max-height: 600px;
    min-width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]
[image: Result]

**How can I let overflow video itself (pic 2) like on thumbnail (pic 1) to see just center of it?**

Answer (score 0):

This works fine might help :)

```css
.main-video {
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.main-video > .video {
   border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-video fixed-top justify-content-center">
    <iframe class="video" width="100%" height="100%"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T0-P3AS4U4U?modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&color=white">
    </iframe>
</div>
```